# Manually assigning key/index to RDD columns in Spark(pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark would like have some suggestions. I have an RDD say `carsrdd` given below.

```
carsrdd=[(u'Ford Mustang', u'6', u'US', 18.0), (u'Mercury Capri 2000', u'4', u'US', 23.0), (u'Chevrolet Impala', u'8', u'US', 52.0)]
```

I want to apply `keyby()` on `carsrdd` with respect to `keys/columns/index` but as default i have to use the `keys` like `(0,1,2,3)` for above rdd. 
but my question is there way to set some `manual keys` to above rdd like i want to use `keys` as say `(2,4,7,8)`.

Is this possible to set a new manual keys for an RDD? I would like to have suggestions for the problem.

Note: I am doing this because i am carrying out series of operation on rdd which further shrink's the rdd thus for this  i need to `preserve` the `keys` of an rdd, for performing further operation on rdd with the `perserved keys`.

Comment: Hey @mtoto, As i want to do series of `keyby()` followed by `reducebykey()` on same rdd, which results in shrinking size of rdd on each `keyby() and reducebykey()` operation , as shriked rdd  causes change in keys of that rdd due to which i have to again change the keys to do `keyby() and reducebykey()` on that respective rdd.

Comment: neither keyby or reducebykey change the keys in your rdd. please illustrate what you mean.

Comment: hi @mtoto, i have asked same question in detail here  [preserving keys of an rdd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276383/preserving-keysindex-of-an-rdd-in-pyspark)

Comment: Hi @NimJ, yes exactly i want to refer  [2,4,7,8] as indices for the RDD instead of default [0,1,2,3] , Is it possible? how can i achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving keys(index) of an RDD in pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276383/preserving-keysindex-of-an-rdd-in-pyspark)

Comment: @eliasah this question is related to [Preserving keys index of an RDD in pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276383/preserving-keysindex-of-an-rdd-in-pyspark) as i had not got any solution for it.

Comment: If you haven't that you add some details and relative content so ppl can help. I still don't see the differences between both questions.

Comment: @eliasah, i have already added all detail here, [Preserving keys index of an RDD in pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276383/preserving-keysindex-of-an-rdd-in-pyspark) as i did not got any solution even i have explained it in detail , so i asked a related question in this thread in more concise way just specifying the problem (i.e manually assigning keys to rdd columns) so that i could get some response related to problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default indexes always starts from zero.

However,one way of using a different reference is by declaring the dictionary with keys as [2,4,7,8] and values as [0,1,2,3] followed by calling it in keyBy.
for eg. if you want to `keyBy()` with index value 7,

```
carsrdd=[(u'Ford Mustang', u'6', u'US', 18.0), (u'Mercury Capri 2000', u'4', u'US', 23.0), (u'Chevrolet Impala', u'8', u'US', 52.0)]

dicto = {2:0,4:1,7:2,8:3}

carsrdd_new = carsrdd.keyBy(lambda x : x[dicto[7]])
carsrdd_new.collect()
```

Output:

```
[(u'US', (u'Ford Mustang', u'6', u'US', 18.0)),
(u'US', (u'Mercury Capri 2000', u'4', u'US', 23.0)),
(u'US', (u'Chevrolet Impala', u'8', u'US', 52.0))]
```

Comment: will try this idea :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `zip` if you know your indexes ahead of time

```
index = sc.parallelize([2,4,7,8])
keyedRdd = index.zip(carsrdd)
```

this will create tuples like -

```
[(2,(u'Ford Mustang', u'6', u'US', 18.0)), 
(4,(u'Mercury Capri 2000', u'4', u'US', 23.0)), 
(7,(u'Chevrolet Impala', u'8', u'US', 52.0))......]
```